# How to make my JavaScript Function for mutli step form work in Laravel

Tags: javascript, html, laravel

I'm making a form for a website and it needs to be multi-step. I followed a guide that showed me a way but I cant seem to get it to work. I'm getting errors I don't understand and I don't get what google is telling about these errors either. The only thing that seems to work are the buttons - the form still submits to my database fine, I just need the lay out to be multistep- any advice would be very helpful.

this is being made with Laravel.

I put the JavaScript in a Js file but I don't know how to call it to make it work - I don't know Js at all.

I removed most questions in the form for convivence

[image]

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
<title>Parents Checklist</title>
<div class="container">
    <section>
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="checklist-card-size">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <br>
                        <form method="POST" class="checklist-form" action="/submit/parentform" multistep>
                            @csrf
                            <div class="">

                                <div class="form-section">
                                    <div class="grid-container">
                                        
                                            <h4>Cognitive</h4>
                              
                                        <div class="grid-labels"><label>Strongly Disagree</label></div>
                                        <div class="grid-labels"><label>Disagree</label></div>
                                        <div class="grid-labels"><label>Neutral</label></div>
                                        <div class="grid-labels"><label>Agree</label></div>
                                        <div class="grid-labels"><label>Strongly Agree</label></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="grid-container" style="background-color: AliceBlue;" id="cog1" type="form-control">
                                        <div><label for="cog1" class="grid-content-left">Does your child show a high level of curiosity?</label></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="1" name="cog1" required></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="2" name="cog1"></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="3" name="cog1"></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="4" name="cog1"></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="5" name="cog1"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="grid-container" id="cog2" type="form-control">
                                        <div><label for="cog2" class="grid-content-left">Does your child show a high-level of reasoning?</label></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="1" name="cog2" required></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="2" name="cog2"></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="3" name="cog2"></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="4" name="cog2"></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="5" name="cog2"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-section">
                                    <div class="grid-container">
                                       <h4>Physical</h4>
                                        
                                        <div class="grid-labels"><label>Strongly Disagree</label></div>
                                        <div class="grid-labels"><label>Disagree</label></div>
                                        <div class="grid-labels"><label>Neutral</label></div>
                                        <div class="grid-labels"><label>Agree</label></div>
                                        <div class="grid-labels"><label>Strongly Agree</label></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="grid-container" style="background-color: AliceBlue;" id="phy17" type="form-control">
                                        <div><label for="phy17" class="grid-content-left">Does your child show speed during physical activities (without a lot of training)?</label></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="1" name="phy17" required></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="2" name="phy17"></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="3" name="phy17"></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="4" name="phy17"></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="5" name="phy17"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="grid-container" id="phy18" type="form-control">
                                        <div><label for="phy18" class="grid-content-left">Does your child show strong muscle control?</label></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="1" name="phy18" required></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="2" name="phy18"></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="3" name="phy18"></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="4" name="phy18"></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="5" name="phy18"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-section">
                                    <div class="grid-container">
                                            <h4>Social-Emotional</h4>
                                        <div class="grid-labels"><label>Strongly Disagree</label></div>
                                        <div class="grid-labels"><label>Disagree</label></div>
                                        <div class="grid-labels"><label>Neutral</label></div>
                                        <div class="grid-labels"><label>Agree</label></div>
                                        <div class="grid-labels"><label>Strongly Agree</label></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="grid-container" style="background-color: AliceBlue;" id="se26" type="form-control">
                                        <div><label for="se26" class="grid-content-left">Does your child show speed during physical activities (without a lot of training)?</label></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="1" name="se26" required></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="2" name="se26"></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="3" name="se26"></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="4" name="se26"></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="5" name="se26"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-section">
                                    <div class="grid-container">
                                        <h4>Spiritual</h4>
                                        <div class="grid-labels"><label>Strongly Disagree</label></div>
                                        <div class="grid-labels"><label>Disagree</label></div>
                                        <div class="grid-labels"><label>Neutral</label></div>
                                        <div class="grid-labels"><label>Agree</label></div>
                                        <div class="grid-labels"><label>Strongly Agree</label></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="grid-container" style="background-color: AliceBlue;" id="spt35" type="form-control">
                                        <div><label for="spt35" class="grid-content-left">Does your child show speed during physical activities (without a lot of training)?</label></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="1" name="spt35" required></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="2" name="spt35"></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="3" name="spt35"></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="4" name="spt35"></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="5" name="spt35"></div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="grid-container" id="spt36" type="form-control">
                                        <div><label for="spt36" class="grid-content-left">Does your child show strong muscle control?</label></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="1" name="spt36" required></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="2" name="spt36"></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="3" name="spt36"></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="4" name="spt36"></div>
                                        <div class="grid-item"><input type="radio" value="5" name="spt36"></div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>

                                <div class="form-navigation">
                                    <button type="button" class="previous btn btn-info float-left">Previous</button>
                                    <button type="button" class="next btn btn-info float-right">Next</button>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sucess float-right">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
 <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function() {
            var $sections = $('.form-section');

            function navigateTo(index) {
                $sections.removeClass('current').eq(index).addClass('current');
                $('.form-navigation .previous').toggle(index > 0);
                var atTheEnd = index >= $sections.length - 1;
                $('.form-navigation .next').toggle(!atTheEnd);
                $('.form-navigation [type=sumbit]').toggle(atTheEnd);
            }

            function curIndex() {
                return $sections.index($sections.filter('.current'));
            }

            $('.form-navigation .previous').click(function() {
                navigateTo(curIndex() - 1);
            });

            $('.form-navigation .next').click(function() {
                $('.checklist-form').parsley().whenValidate({
                    group: 'block-' + curIndex()
                }).done(function() {
                    navigateTo(curIndex() + 1);
                });
            });

            $sections.each(function(index, section) {
                $(section).find(':input').attr('data-parsley-group', 'block-' + index);
            });
            navigateTo(0);
        });
    </script>
</div>

@endsection
```

Comment: Make a vue component with your html and all scripts, they work well with laravel

Comment: @ZloiGoroh I dont know what that is unfortunately